# How to use the Washington, DC Metro API

Tags: json, api, rest

I've been researching how I can take the transit info API that [The Washington DC Metro Rail](http://developer.wmata.com/docs) offers, and display it as HTML.

The documentation is on their website, but It does not include many examples. The only instructions I've found is to use one of three URLs.

I have figured out how to see the information using the below code. The problem is that the URLs below are generating all data as text only in my browser. I cannot figure out how to display selected data as HTML.

from their site:

> Each method has 2 endpoints: REST and JSON.
>
> URL (REST) example:
>   api.wmata.com/StationPrediction.svc/GetPrediction/A10?api_key=YOUR_API_KEY
>
> URL (JSON) example:
>   api.wmata.com/StationPrediction.svc/json/GetPrediction/A10?api_key=YOUR_API_KEY
>
> Additionally, developers can use JSONP if desired by adding a
>   "callback" parameter to the JSON call:
>
> http://[url to JSON service]?api_key=[your_key]&callback=[name of
>   callback]
>
> When using JSONP make sure that [name of callback] in the URL
>   displayed above is the name of a Javascript function needed to process
>   the JSON data.

Can anyone point me in the right direction for a tutorial or best way to get started?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You should try the WMATA interactive documentation.

http://developer.wmata.com/io-docs

If you've already registered for a key, just sign in, and your API key will be automatically populated into the interactive docs. The I/O Docs interface should help you easily navigate the resources/methods. If you have any other questions, feel free to ask here, and I can help you out.

I'm a platforms evangelist for Mashery, the company that helps WMATA/DC Metro manage their APIs.